# Arrange a polynominal

Tags: polynomials, factorization

I have a complex polynomial in more than ten line. I want to rearrange it by the power of another polynomial. For example, I have a powers of (1-A(x)/x^2) as a factor in it, and I want to sort the main polynomial, by the this factor. How I can do?

Comment: If you can edit your post to compactly clearly show your complex polynomial and your A polynomial then someone might be able to test a couple of methods and see if any of those will work on your problem. Otherwise "I got some complicated polynomials, what do I do" is unlikely to get any advice that will work.

Comment: The question is short, so is the answer. Write a conjectured polynomial with unknown coefficients. Substitute therein the given short polynomial. Determine the unknown coefficients with the help of `SolveAlways` by equating it to the original one. Please provide details if you want a more complete solution.